# How do you submit a rails 3 form without refreshing the page?

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I've seen this done using ajax & php, but not rails 3.

I've tried using:

```
<%= form_for(:technician, :url => {:controller => 'pos', :action => 'create_ticket'}, :remote => true) do |f| %>
```

but the page still refreshes each time.  I'm building a point of sale program, so I don't want the page to refresh.

How do I send the form data to the controller to process and store in the database without refreshing?

Comment: This code _should_ send an ajax request, as long as you have a proper rails.js file included. Could you post the generated html code on pastebin.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Rails 3 and coming of the UJS, the simple fact of adding the remote attribute is sufficient to transform a request to AJAX.

But, for the request is handled as AJAX, this implies you have the Rails javascript library loaded.

That means, you should include the rails.js file on your header.

In your layout.erb.html, you should find

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

And in your public/javascripts directory, you should find :

```
application.js, controls.js, dragdrop.js, effects.js, prototype.js, rails.js
```

Then it should work.

Comment: I have all those files and the code, but it still doesn't work.  I have timers on the page and when I submit, the timer resets.

Answer (score -1):

If in rails, you should make some file also in .js format and render it after save in controller. For example render create.js after save in create controller. In file create.js.erb, you should render back what you want to view after save that form