# How do I submit the associated section of a form remotely in Rails without submitting the entire form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, activerecord, erb

I have a simple Rails form that allows for its associated parent to be edited. I would like to allow the user to submit this section of the form using :remote => true so that the user can add a new parent, and then select the parent in an updated select menu elsewhere in the form. As you can see in the code, I added a submit button to the parents' part of the form, and it even knows whether to say "Create" or "Update," but when I submit it the entire page is refreshed, the entire form is submitted for validation and so forth. How can I accomplish what I want in Rails?

Here is the code in question:

```
<%= form_for @sermon, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :date %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :date %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Speaker" %><br />
    <%= f.select :speaker_id, Speaker.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {:include_blank => true} %>
  </div>
    <% @sermon.build_speaker unless @sermon.speaker %>
        <%= f.fields_for :speaker, :remote => true, :html => {:data_type => 'html', :id => 'create_speaker_form'} do |g| %>
            <%= g.label :name, "Or, add a new speaker:" %><br />
            <%= g.text_field :name %>
            <%= g.submit %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

probably your question has been answered here [How do you submit a rails 3 form without refreshing the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639168/how-do-you-submit-a-rails-3-form-without-refreshing-the-page)

if that doesn't help you can try using [preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) attaching it to your submit button.

Comment: That's not really the question -- I have an associated form within the main form I'm trying to submit.